# How to change default values in autoconf

Tags: linux, autoconf, automake

I'm using autoconf to generate a `configure` shell script based on an `configure.ac` input file.

By default, the generated configure script supports the option `--enable-shared`  , which has default value "yes".  I.e., `./configure --help | grep enable-shared`

```
--enable-shared[=PKGS]  build shared libraries [default=yes]
```

This seems to be a standard option that is always included in configure scripts.  But, is there a way to have the `configure` shell script generated such that its default value for  `--enable-shared` is `no` ?  I presume this requires me either to put some special AC_ARG_??? statements in my `configure.ac` file, or, provide command line options to autoconf.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, this is as easy as providing an option to a libtool macro...

In `configure.ac`, it's a good idea to check if your libtool installation is recent enough - the current stable release being [2.4.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/) :

**`LT_PREREQ([2.4.2])`** # not 'technically' required, but good practice.

Followed by setting the relevant option in the [`LT_INIT`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libtool.html#LT_005fINIT) macro:

**`LT_INIT([disable-shared])`**